# Divisor class group of noetherian local domain and its completion or henselization

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Assume $R$ is a noetherian local domain, we know that if $\hat R$ is UFD then $R$ is also a UFD, see [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/79641/ufd-property-descends). However, the converse is not true as the completion may not even be a domain (so we cannot define it's divisor class group in general), see [tag/0AL7](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0AL7).

Inspired by above observation and the fact a normal domain is a UFD if and only if it's divisor class group vanishes, I am interested in the relationship of divisor class group between $R$ and $\hat R$.

Here is my question:

1. If $\hat R$ is a domain then we can define $Cl(\hat R)$. In this case, what's the relationship of $Cl(R)$ and $Cl(\hat R)$ ?
2. Henselization behaves better than completion as $R^h$ is a normal domain if and only if $R$ is, see [tag/07QL](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/07QL). So what's the relationship of $Cl(R)$ and $Cl(R^h)$ ? Is that $R$ is a UFD equivalent to that $R^h$ is a UFD?

Comment: In most cases of interest, you will have a map $Cl(R)\to Cl(\hat{R})$, which may not be surjective. This happens even for some rational double points on a surface.

Comment: In “On Brauer groups of some rational normal local rings” by Lindsay N. Childs, it is mentioned there’s an injection $\mathrm{Br}(R)/\mathrm{Br}(K)$ to $\mathrm{Cl}(R^h)/\mathrm{Cl}(R)$, not sure if this helps..

Comment: @Qixiao Thank you for the paper, I didn't notice that before.